# FormatException Error String to DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, string, datetime

I have been sitting on my seat for over an hour not knowing what's the error.. Could someone please assist?

[image: Error]

Error is said to be "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

The field name "LastLoginTime" is a DATETIME datatype in my database.

These are the codes..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuditNLoggingDAO al = new AuditNLoggingDAO();

    int result = 0;

    int resultLogout = 0;

    DateTime dateTimeOfLatestLogin = DateTime.MinValue;

    //Get IP Address of Client's Machine
    String externalIP = null;
    try
    {
        externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")).Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("Retrieval of IP Address", "IP Address", ex);
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoginUserName"].ToString()))
        {
            String loginUsername = Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();

            //Get latest Login time
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds = al.getAuditData(Session["LoginUserName"].ToString());

            foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                dateTimeOfLatestLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(r["LastLoginTime"]);
            }

            result = al.trackLogout(loginUsername, DateTime.Now, externalIP, Convert.ToDouble(latitudeTB.Value), Convert.ToDouble(longitudeTB.Value));
            resultLogout = al.updateLLogoutT(loginUsername, DateTime.Now, externalIP);
        }

        loginDetails.InnerText = "You logged into your account at " + dateTimeOfLatestLogin.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd/MM/yyyy") + " SGT.";
        logoutDetails.InnerText = "You logged out from your session at " + (DateTime.Now).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd/MM/yyyy") + " SGT.";
    }
}
```

I can't seemt to be able to find the mistake.. I'm guessing it's my ***dateTimedateTimeOfLatestLogin*** variable..

al.trackLogout method,

```
//Track Logout Activity
public int trackLogout(String username, DateTime dateTimeActivity, String ipaddress, Double latitude, Double longitude)
{
    int result = 0;

    StringBuilder sqlCmd = new StringBuilder();
    sqlCmd.AppendLine("INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) ");
    sqlCmd.AppendLine("VALUES (@addUsername, @addDT, @addIPAddress, @addLat, @addLng, @addActivity)");

    try
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionStr);

        myConn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.ToString(), myConn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addUsername", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addDT", dateTimeActivity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addIPAddress", ipaddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addLat", latitude);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addLng", longitude);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addActivity", "Logout");

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConn.Close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("AuditNLoggingDAO.trackLogout", sqlCmd.ToString(), ex);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `dateTimeOfLatestLogin  = (DateTime)r["LastLoginTime"];`

Comment: What does LastLoginTime look like when you put it into your watch window?

Comment: If I had a guess at this, I think you may have a problem with string format of the date time value not being recognised due to the current culture value. The way I've always done datetime conversion is to use DateTime.ParseExact().

Comment: @domster, what is the value of `LastLoginTime`?

Comment: @Mauricio The value is {31/07/2017 22:08:12}.

Comment: @aquinas when i set a breakpoint to check my autos it looks like {31/07/2017 22:08:12}.

Comment: @Damon i tried using that but i still got the same error which is odd....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving a DateTime value from a DataRow (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106204/retrieving-a-datetime-value-from-a-datarow-c)

Comment: Interesting, would have thought this would work: CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateTimeOfLatestLogin  = DateTime.ParseExact(r["LastLoginTime"], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider);

Comment: What is the signature of `al.trackLogout`

Comment: @domster put a breakpoint within that method, it may be inside that method.  If that method is in a Web-Service outside of the Solution, you may need to run Debugger in two sessions, to capture the breakpoint

Comment: @Damon i used dateTimeOfLatestLogin = DateTime.ParseExact(r["LastLoginTime"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider); the r[    ] had to have ToString()

Comment: @Damon the error persists..

Comment: @domster try: `r["LastLoginTime"].ToString();`

Comment: @domster is the `DateTimeActivity` field in table `AuditActivity` a DateTime or VarChar type?

Comment: it's DateTime type..

Comment: i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417770/datetime-conversion-and-parsing still doesn't work.. it's so strange....

Comment: @domster put a break-point on the `r["LastLoginTime"]` conversion to DateTime to validate the conversion...It is in your SQL...you need to move out of `StringBuilder` and move to `SqlCommand`

Comment: @GoldBishop i have come across only this error after so long of using StringBuilder. SB was taught in school.. What information you might actually require from the break-point?

Comment: @domster....ahh the fallacy of school....great on theory, not so great in practice....going to refactor your method in VB, current environment i have.

Comment: @GoldBishop you bet.. it's insufficient in practicality.. okay sure.. thank you

Comment: You're saying when you add a watch on `r["LastLoginTime"]` it looks like this: `{31/07/2017 22:08:12}`? And it says the type of C# variable is a DateTime?

Comment: @aquinas i'll upload an image

Comment: @domster, regarding `aquinas` response, your date format generally needs to be in the Localization pattern of your time setup on the Database server.

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought the error was happening here `dateTimeOfLatestLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(r["LastLoginTime"]);
` not in your al.trackLogout method. So...if it's happening in THAT method, Which line is it blowing up on?

Comment: @aquinas it started the invalid data...it was blowing up at the SQL though....that was the source of the problem.

Comment: @aquinas now im confused.. the error being in al.trackLogout method? I thought it's more of the conversion to be displayed for the later part. An example of the format of LastLoginTime in the database table is 31/07/2017 22:55:05

Comment: dateTimeOfLatestLogin = DateTime.ParseExact(r["LastLoginTime"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider); is this correct then? i'm currently using this.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068386/parsing-datetime-on-localized-systems

Comment: Paste the COMPLETE stack trace of the error. As it stands, it's not obvious to me exactly which line is causing the error.

Comment: @domster You need to bring your Application into consistency with your Database environment....your application seems to have one DateTime pattern and your Database is expecting another.  By Default, MS-SQL defaults to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

Comment: what might actually be the exact reason for this error.. it makes me wonder.

Comment: @domster what is the database product you are submitting to?  What is that RDBMS datetime settings?  Execute a simple `select getdate()` (For MS-SQL) to see the datetime format the RDBMS is expecting

Comment: @domster Also, Execute a test SQL statement against the RDBMS with all the values as the Application will submit them to see if it likes the various values and stores them in the format you are expecting.

Comment: You should REALLY paste the complete stack trace...

Comment: I realised the error was actually "Convert.ToDouble(latitudeTB.Value), Convert.ToDouble(longitudeTB.Value)" The date is working well.

Comment: The codes i posted in my question actually work too, but the Latitude and Longitude was affecting the whole process.. I added an answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Revised Codes that i'm using right now..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuditNLoggingDAO al = new AuditNLoggingDAO();

    int result = 0;

    int resultLogout = 0;

    //Get IP Address of Client's Machine
    String externalIP = null;
    try
    {
        externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")).Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("Retrieval of IP Address", "IP Address", ex);
    }

    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoginUserName"].ToString()))
    {
        String loginUsername = Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();

        //Get latest Login time
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = al.getAuditData(Session["LoginUserName"].ToString());

        DateTime dateTimeOfLatestLogin = DateTime.MinValue;

        /*foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //dateTimeOfLatestLogin = DateTime.ParseExact(r["LastLoginTime"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            String dtDBString = r["LastLoginTime"].ToString();
            dateTimeOfLatestLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDBString);

            //Debug.WriteLine(dateTimeOfLatestLogin);
            //"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
        }*/

        String DBConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionStr);
        string sql = "select LastLoginTime FROM AuditTrails WHERE Username=@USERID";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERID", loginUsername);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string timeTaken = reader["LastLoginTime"].ToString();
                    dateTimeOfLatestLogin = Convert.ToDateTime(timeTaken);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            logManager log = new logManager();
            log.addLog("LogoutWithDesc.aspx.cs", "PageLoad", ex);
        }

        resultLogout = al.updateLLogoutT(loginUsername, DateTime.Now, externalIP);
        result = al.trackLogout(loginUsername, externalIP, Convert.ToDouble(latitudeTB.Value), Convert.ToDouble(longitudeTB.Value));

        loginDetails.InnerText = "You logged into your account at " + dateTimeOfLatestLogin.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd/MM/yyyy") + " SGT.";
        logoutDetails.InnerText = "You logged out from your session at " + (DateTime.Now).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd/MM/yyyy") + " SGT.";
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not C# but don't have a C# project open to write in, so it is in VB.Net; minor syntax tweaks and changes but otherwise the same:

```
Public Function trackLogout(username As String, dateTimeActivity As DateTime, ipaddress As String, latitude As Double, longitude As Double) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(DBConnectionStr)
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) ")
            sb.AppendLine("VALUES (@addUsername, @addDT, @addIPAddress, @addLat, @addLng, @addActivity)")

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand() With {.CommandText = sb.ToString(), .Connection = conn, .CommandType = CommandType.Text}
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addUsername", username)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addDT", dateTimeActivity)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addIPAddress", ipaddress)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addLat", latitude)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addLng", longitude)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addActivity", "Logout")

                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = -1
        ' Whatever your current implementation is.
    End Try

    Return result
End Function
```

Unfortunately, doing inline sql execution requires StringBuilder.  You were correct on that.  I use Stored Procedures to execute structured SQL Statements, so I do not have to manage the SQL in the application.

Comment: @domster this is a more readable approach....your error is between the Application DateTime value and the SQL expected DateTime format

Comment: have you tried executing the SQL Statement with the values when it errors out?

Comment: @domster effectively executing your inline sql statement with all the variables `@...` replace with the values.  This will allow you to see how the Application is sending the data back and how the Database is reacting to those values

Comment: @domster Try inserting `31/07/2017 22:08:12` into the DateTime field

Comment: In the sql query statement it should be written like this? '31/07/2017 22:08:12' with the single quotations?

Comment: I used this sqlquery statement to test "INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', CONVERT(DateTime, '31/07/2017 22:08:12'), 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', x.x, x.x, 'Logout')" and i get this error, The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the datatype that this datetime provided or the format itself is nvarchar/string?

Comment: i've been saving the values of datetime as datetime with DateTime.Now being the value of the variables. I used to use nvarchar but for this website im using DateTime.

Comment: @domster try inserting the datetime value as `'7/31/2017 22:08:12'`

Comment: the database value ended up to be 31/07/2017 22:08:12

Comment: @domster execute this statement `INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', '31/07/2017 22:08:12', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', x.x, x.x, 'Logout')`

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
I received this error for the statement u requested to be executed

Comment: @domster `INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', '2017-07-31 22:08:12', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', x.x, x.x, 'Logout')`

Comment: INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', '2017-07-31 22:08:12', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', x.x, x.x, 'Logout')
This one works

Comment: @domster one more `INSERT INTO AuditActivity (Username, DateTimeActivity, IPAddressActivity, LatitudeActivity, LongitudeActivity, ActivityType) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', '7/31/2017 22:08:12', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', x.x, x.x, 'Logout')`

Comment: if i'm not wrong, the format of the DateTime follows my system datetime format?

Comment: @domster ok....so .Net is more forgiving and will try all patterns; whereas SQl is less forgiving and will require a specific date-time pattern.  SQL will ALWAYS accept UTC patterns but otherwise use this article as a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

Comment: @domster .Net uses Localization in representing the datetime values; SQL does not use Localization, by default.  If you want it to be attuned with your TimeZone's standard Date Time format, you will need to have it setup.  You would think that SQL would extract the localization format but since the SQL Server could be in the UK and the application in Pakistan, they use a Universal DateTime format, by default.  So, ISO-8601 is the default pattern

Comment: I'll refer to it.. Will get back once i solve. My project mate is helping me out too.. Damn didn't know this minor error would cause so much hassle.

Comment: @domster welcome to System Design and Developing...read up on DateTime formats and expectations ;)

Comment: sorry just to clarify, i myself am a little lost.. the error lies in the conversion of the value retrieved from the database table column?

Comment: Your application was passing the DateTime value as `dd/MM/yyy ....` but SQL was expecting either `MM/dd/yyy ...` or (ISO) `yyyy-MM-dd ...`.  In either case, your applications value did not "jive" with SQL's expected format and "threw up" all over the execution.

Comment: But using DateTime.Now to store this value into the database, SQL will automatically convert to the universal format of its own?

Comment: @domster that is correct...although I am unsure how it will behave from a Inline SQL execution.  In theory, it should work but no guarantees ;)

Comment: alright.. i'll try my best to take it from here. thank you bishop! you're gold!